# 'terraform plan' NOT updating state file

Tags: terraform

Tried the following:

Resource creation(ec2) using terraform>>manually edit a resource(changed type) from AWS console>>run 'terraform plan'>>shows changes required after doing 'terraform refresh' internally BUT state file is not getting updated?

Looks like some bug.

(article states refresh is done automatically, it should affect the state file?-
https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html)

I note that Manually running 'terraform refresh' updates the state file to reflect present state of infrastructure(which then would be compared with config file ie desired state).

Regards.

Aditya

Comment: Why would you expect it to update the state file? And why do you need that behaviour? Normally the state file would be updated by `apply` or `destroy` which is when Terraform is actually making changes. As you've noticed, you can run `terraform refresh` to force a refresh and update the state file but this isn't normally required.

Comment: Because the document says 'terraform plan' internally runs a 'refresh' which means the state file should get updated to reflect the current infrastructure.

Comment: @ydaetskcoR - the OP could be using `-refresh=true` flag, which is the same as running `tf refresh` before the plan. I agree that this shouldn't be necessary unless you've got something else wrong but it is possible.

Comment: @AdityaGarg - no it doesn't say that. 2nd paragraph states `This command is a convenient way to check whether the execution plan for a set of changes matches your expectations without making any changes to real resources or to the state`. It does run a refresh, but it doesn't say that it updates the state file, it explicitly states that it doesn't.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer thanks for that, the second para explicitly mentions that 'state' is not affected. So in summary, its not treated like a normal 'terraform refresh'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks @Software Engineer

The second para explicitly mentions that 'state' is not affected. So in summary, its not treated like a normal 'terraform refresh'.
[IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz5mF.png)

https://www.terraform.io/docs/cli/commands/plan.html

Answer (score 2):

As per the latest documentation the plan operation implicitly does refresh unless you specify refresh=false as a parameter.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As per the below documentation link, you can update your state file without making modifications to your infrastructure using the -refresh-only flag for plan and apply operations.

https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/tutorials/state/refresh

[image]

But when I checked with terraform version 1.66, it's still not working properly

**Test Scenario**:

- Created an instance (instanceA) using Terraform resource block.
- Manually deleted instanceA from the console.

**Execution Steps**:--

- Run terraform plan -refresh=false -> No changes expected.
- Run terraform plan -refresh-only -> Note: Objects have changed outside of Terraform, but it will not make any changes in the terraform.tfstate file.
- Run terraform refresh -> Removed instanceA from the terraform.tfstate file.
- Run terraform plan -refresh=false -> Plan: 1 to add, 0 to change, 0 to destroy.
- Run terraform plan -refresh-only -> No changes. Your infrastructure still matches the configuration.

but **-refresh-only** option working fine when using it with apply command like this:

```
$ terraform apply -refresh-only

Would you like to update the Terraform state to reflect these detected changes?
  Terraform will write these changes to the state without modifying any real infrastructure.
  There is no undo. Only 'yes' will be accepted to confirm.

  Enter a value: yes
```